# Does Azure Purview have a data lineage API?

Tags: azure, azure-purview, data-governance

I know there are connectors for Purview that support data lineage data collection.  However, I'm wondering if Purview has any sort of API that allows any data processing (ETL) process to write a lineage record/document to the Purview lineage repository?

Answer (score 0):

It's built on [Apache Atlas](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/azure-purview-catalog-is-based-on-apache-atlas-8e340830cabe) - Data Governance and Metadata framework for Hadoop.